# mod.cu(66): error: identifier "cudnnSetFilterNdDescriptor_v4" is undefined

Tags: theano-cuda

When I compile my python produce written with theano in Linux.I got a compile error in the picture.All path set well.This error suddenly appeared with no operation.
[image]

Comment: I do not understand why this post was downvoted without any explanation. I got the same error and am looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen such error when running Theano 0.9 with CUDA 8 and cuDNN 6. 
The error is fixed if using cuDNN 5.15 instead.